# ¿Por qué no puedo unirme a salas de chat con socket.io y node.js?

Tags: php, nodejs, socket.io

¿Cuál es la mejor forma para poder unirme directamente a un chat en específico y empezar a chatear con esa persona que está unida a ese chat creado?

Mi pseudocódigo lo he pensado así:

1. Cambiar mi `index.html` como lo indica la documentación y en su lugar pueda usar un archivo `.php`. Estuve investigando en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373350/change-index-html-to-index-php-returns-save-binary-file) pero no me fue tampoco de mucha ayuda.
2. Notificarle a mi `index.js` que alguien está tratando de unirse a un chat en específico (trayendo ya el id del chat creado por la primera persona y ya guardado previamente en mi base de datos desde node.js)
3. Ya haciendo el enlace, quiero hacerle saber a mi `index.js` a dónde mandar los mensajes (que sería obviamente al chat al cual le he especificado en mi paso 2).

Para crear mi chat he seguido esto de la [documentación oficial de socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) Para poder hacer la funcionalidad de crear `rooms` he seguido esta [documentación oficial](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).

Mi código que tengo hasta el momento funcionando tal como lo expliqué antes es el siguiente:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="messenger" action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>      


    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      $('form#messenger').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

El cual trabaja bien y luce de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por parte del código node.js que sirve para convivir del lado del servidor es:

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){

  var name_room = randomstring(10);

  socket.join(name_room);

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.to(name_room).emit('chat message', msg);
    console.log("mensajeenviado", msg);
    console.log("name_room", name_room);
  });
});

function randomstring(password_length = 25) {
    var string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789",
        password = "";
    for ( var c = 0; c < password_length; c++ ) {
        var rand = parseInt(((Math.random()) * string.length) +1);
        password += string.charAt(rand);
    }
    return password;
}
```

Soy nuevo en el mundo de `node.js` y `socket.io` por lo que las preguntas y respuestas que cito a continuación no me han sido de mucha ayuda. Quisiera me pudieran orientar sobre cómo poder lograr algo así, ya que no lo he conseguido hasta el momento. Gracias.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444817/socket-io-chat-with-private-rooms
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778881/socket-io-sending-parameter-to-php-file
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435673/socket-io-send-message-to-specific-room-client-side

Comment: ¿La idea es chat uno a uno o muchos a muchos?

Comment: Sería de uno a uno nada más.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es parte de un proyecto antiguo y no estoy del todo seguro de que funcione, pero seguramente te dará la idea por dónde comenzar.

Lo primero es que vas a necesitar sesiones, tanto del lado de PHP como de Node.js para identificar usuarios y poder establecer la conversación entre ellos:

```
var datos = {
    id:'<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>',
    usuario:'<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>',
    cuarto:'<?php echo $_SESSION['chat_room']; ?>'
    // El cuarto puede ser valor vacío, para crearlo con formulario
    // Puede provenir de $_POST (del paso anterior)
    // O puede ser de $_GET si creaste un listado de cuartos
    // Puedes agregar tantos datos como necesites
};
```

HTML:

```
        <!-- socket.io -->
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <!-- jquery 1.6.4 -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- chat config -->
        <script src="/javascripts/chat.js"></script>
        <div class="roomsOut" id="rooms"></div>
```

En #rooms insertas el formulario para crear cuarto y la lista de cuartos disponibles.

El cliente (chat.js)

```
var chatUrl = window.location.origin + ':3200';
var socket = io.connect(chatUrl);

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Iniciar sesión de usuario
    socket.emit('adduser', datos);
    // Mantienes el mismo listener
    // Aunque probablemente debas activarlo / desactivarlo
    // Dependiendo si está en cuarto o no
    $('form#messenger').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });
});

function join(room) {
    socket.emit('join', room);
}

function quit(room) {
    socket.emit('quit', room);
}

socket.on('update rooms', function(rooms, current) {
    foreach(rooms as room) {
        if(room == current) {
            // No mostrar enlace
            var link = '<li>' + room + '</li>';
        } else {
            // Crear enlace para unirse al cuarto
            var link = '<a href="#" onclick="join(' + "'" + room + "'" + '); return false;">' + room + '</a>';
        }
        $("#rooms").append(link);
    }
});

socket.on('update chat', function(usuario, mensaje) {
    // usuario: Quién envía el mensaje
    // mensaje: Texto
    // Nombre de quien envió el mensaje
    var texto = '<span class="chat-usuario">' + usuario + '</span>';
    // Mensaje completo
    $("#messages").append('<li>' + texto + mensaje + '</li>';
    // Hacer scroll para que el último mensaje sea visible
    // $("#messages").scrollTop = $("#messages").scrollHeight; // No recuerdo si funciona en jQuery
});
```

El Servidor (omito la configuración y voy directo con conexiones):

```
// Usuarios con sesión
var usernames = {};
// Cuartos creados
var rooms = [];


// Inicializar escucha
socket.on('connection', function(sockets) {
    // Conexión de usuario
    sockets.on('adduser', function(data){
    // Guardar datos de usuario
        sockets.username = data.usuario;
        sockets.room = data.cuarto;
        // Agregar id a lista global
        usernames[data.id] = data.usuario;
        // Verificar si existe el cuarto
        var exists = 0;
        var index = 0;
        for(index; index < rooms.length; index++){
           if(rooms[index] == data.cuarto){
               exists++;
               // Sí existe, fin del ciclo
               break;
           }
        }
        // No existe, hay que crearlo
        if(exists == 0) {
            rooms.push(data.cuarto);
        }
        // Unir cliente al cuarto
        sockets.join(data.cuarto);

        // Notificar que el usuario se conectó
        sockets.broadcast.to(cuarto).emit('update chat', 'SISTEMA', username + ' se ha conectado ');
        // Actualizar cuartos
        sockets.emit('update rooms', rooms, cuarto);
        console.log(rooms);
    });

    // Enviar mensaje
    sockets.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        socket.in(sockets.room).emit('update chat', sockets.username, msg);
    });

    // Cambiar de cuarto
    sockets.on('join', function(newroom){
        sockets.leave(sockets.room);
        sockets.join(newroom);
        sockets.emit('update chat', 'SISTEMA', 'te has conectado la sala ' + newroom);
        // Mensaje a cuarto anterior
        sockets.broadcast.to(sockets.room).emit('update chat', 'SISTEMA', sockets.username + ' ha dejado la sala');
        // Actualizar nombre del cuarto actual
        sockets.room = newroom;
        sockets.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SISTEMA', sockets.username+' se ha unido a la sala');
        sockets.emit('update rooms', rooms, newroom);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    sockets.on('quit', function(){
        // Eliminar sesión de usuario
        delete usernames[sockets.id];
        // Notificar que el usuario salió
        sockets.broadcast.to(sockets.room).emit('update chat', 'SISTEMA', sockets.username + ' se ha desconectado');
    // Sacar usuario del cuarto
        sockets.leave(sockets.room);
    });
});
```

Es probable que haya errores, porque aparte de ser un proyecto antiguo, también tuve que adaptar algunas cosas para simplificar.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo. Había estado fuera y no pude revisar tu respuesta. Hoy voy a probar a ver si por lo menos me da la idea de lo que necesito hacer y te platico, gracias!